# How to index identical item in python?

Tags: python-3.x, indexing

```
lst = [1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1]

x = lst[4]

print(lst.index(x))
```

The last line prints 0.

What if I wanted to return the item at the original index of four. Is there a way to the original, rather than an equavalent element in the list?

Edit: To be clear, I want the last line to print 4.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want to do. Get all occurences of `1` in the list? Or get the 4th element rather than the 1st? If the specific format of the list ins't that important, you could try something with enumerate.

Comment: I want to know how to return 4.

Comment: Does the specific format of the list matter? Or could it be edited in a specific way?

Comment: the order of each element is important. but the format isn't.

Comment: Why return ``4``?, Why not ``6``, or ``7``? Python does not know that ``x`` is the `1` at position 4 - in fact all the ``1``s are likely the *exact same* object in contemporary Python implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the format of the list doesn't matter, you could try using the enumerate class (a generator object):

```py
lst = [x for x in enumerate((1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1))]
x = lst[4]
lst.index(x) # This should return 4 rather than 0.
```

EDIT: Instead of doing `lst.index(x)` to get the index, you could do `x[0]` which will also return 4.

The only problem is that you're going to have to write some changes to your code. If you tried to print x, the result would be `[4, 1]`. If you wanted to simply gather the value, you would have to print `x[1]`. The enumerate class is a generator object, that when iterated over yields a list in the form of `[index, value]`. If you have any other questions, please comment and I'll do my best to answer them.

Comment: This is a bit pointless, since you could just use ``x[0]`` to get ``4``. No need for ``.index`` in this case.

Comment: What do you mean? 4 is not an element in the list, so `x[0]` will give you one rather than `4`

Comment: ``lst`` is a list of ``(<index>, <value>)`` tuples. ``x[0]`` does return ``4``, it is ``x[1]`` that returns ``1``.

Comment: when I run this code it throw up the following error: "TypeError: enumerate() takes at most 2 arguments (8 given)"

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't understand your first comment. I was trying to keep the code as similar as before, but I'll update my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @user11655340 sorry, the code is fixed. I forgot to include an extra set of parantheses. The enumerate function takes a list or tuple, rather than a massive set of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

`index(obj)` return only the index of the first item equal to obj, if you want to search from a certain position you can use `index(obj, start)`, example:

```
>>> l = [0, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0, 10, 1]
>>> l.index(1, 5)
>>> 7
```

if you want to jump a certain number of item equals to your obj you can use a loop:

```
def my_index(l, obj, after=0):
    for i, item in enumerate(l):
        if item == obj:
            if after == 0:
                return i
            after -= 1

    raise ValueError(str(obj) + ' is not in list') # nothing was found
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've resolved `lst[4]` to `1`, that value is just an integer value with no information about where it came from. If you need to be able to go back from the value to the index in the original list, you'll have to either make the entry unique or keep the indexes you are interested in stored somewhere else.

To make the entries unique, you could store the index along with each value in the list, like this:

```
lst = [[(0,1),(1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(4,1),(5,0),(6,1),(7,1)]]
```

To fetch a value:

```
x_entry = lst[4]
x_val = x_entry[1]
```

To find it's original position in the list:

```
index = x_entry[0]
```

If you want to generate that data structure automatically, you can loop through the list with `enumerate()` to get the index of each entry:

```
lst = [1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1]
annotated_lst = []
for i, val in enumerate(lst):
    annotated_lst.append((i, val))
```